# interpreting var a=b.c={} in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was going through `node.js` where i came across something like this `var exports = module.exports = {};` in the modules section .

This would be much similar to `var a=b.c={}`, how do i visualize it?

What's happening here?

From what i can understand is that both `a` and `b` are assigned as object, they both describe the same thing or is it that they both references same thing?

**Example**

```
exports.sayHelloInEnglish = function() {
  return "HELLO";
};

exports.sayHelloInSpanish = function() {
  return "Hola";
};
```

Same as

```
module.exports = {
  sayHelloInEnglish: function() {
    return "HELLO";
  },

  sayHelloInSpanish: function() {
    return "Hola";
  }
};
```

Can someone please explain it to me in much simpler terms?

Comment: @AndrewLi You are wrong, it's more like `var a = {}, b.c = a;`

Comment: @ponury-kostek No, that's incorrect. Assignment expressions evaluate to their right operand.

Comment: It's neither really. It would be `b.c = {}; var a = b.c;`. Important difference because `a` and `b.c` are a reference to the same object.

Comment: @AndrewLi - In your example, `a` and `b.c` point to DIFFERENT objects (both initially empty).  That's not the same as `a = b.c = {}` where they point at the SAME object - modify one and the other sees the same modification.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, I realized that. But assignment expressions do evaluate to their right operand, and in this case that would mean a reference would be assigned to `a` as it was to `b.c`.

Comment: @AndrewLi Proof that you are wrong https://repl.it/JWPO/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `var exports = module.exports = {};`, how do i visualize it?

First make sure to understand how it is parsed, what components the syntax consists of. It's basically two nested assignments<sup>1</sup>:

```
var exports = (module.exports = {});
```

You can translate this into the equivalent

```
var _temp = {};
module.exports = _temp;
var exports = _temp;
```

So yes, they both will contain the same object.

<sub>1: Grammatically it's an assignment expression in the initialiser of a variable declaration, but for ease of understanding we ignore the `var`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[image]

According to the parse tree of the statement, here are the things that happen in order.

1. The object b will be added with a member called c or if it already exists, it is accessed.
2. b.c is set to the literal {}
3. The value of a is set to the value of b.c
   In step 3, it means both refer to the same thing.

For example, you can try this.

```
 var a = [1,5]
 var b = a
 b[1] = 2
 console.log(a)
 console.log(b)
```

Both will have updated values.

Comment: The step "*The object a is created.*" makes no sense

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It should be a variable.

Comment: But the variable creation is hoisted, it doesn't really fit in step 3) either

Comment: I didn't know about hoisting.